# Does THREE.Raycaster perform intersection checks on CSS3DObject objects?

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I need to run raycast off mouse coordinates and check for intersections on a group of Three CSS3DObject objects.

Here is the function:

```
RayCastCheck = function(event, objects){
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth)*2 - 1, -(event.clientX / window.innerHeight )*2 + 1, 0.5);
    new THREE.Projector().unprojectVector( vector, camera);
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
    console.log(intersects.length);
};
```

---

The objects argument is an array of `css3dobjects`. I am able to use similar function to target drops on the scene to the correct mouse location so I believe my calculation of the mouse point in world space is correct.  This led to believe that the Raycaster is does not check intersections on `css3dobjects`.

My css3dobjects are typically constructed with a div as its element.

```
createObject = function(){
  var element = document.createElement("div");    
  var obj = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element);
  scene.add(obj);
}
```

My scene is created via this function

```
//global
var scene;
var camera;
var renderer;

createScene = function(){
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 400 / 600, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 500;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(400, 600);
$(#body).appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}
```

Do I have all the required elements in the scene to enable raycasting?

Is it possible to perform raycasting on `css3dobjects` with the `css3drenderer`?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the usual events with the dom elements. You can even get the relative coordinates:

```
var x = e.offsetX==undefined?e.layerX:e.offsetX;
var y = e.offsetY==undefined?e.layerY:e.offsetY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Raycaster on css3dobjects won't work. At least this is what I figured out.

Take a look at three.js r76 line 8933. There is the definition of the "raycast" function of the css3dobject. 
It is empty so it isn't implemented and won't work because of this of course. probably on a further version. would need this function too

Still isn't implemented in r78.

Comment: I got it to work, CSS3D objects are just PlaneGeometry, instead of subclassing CSS3DObject with Object3D use Mesh with a PlaneGeometry with you div width/height and a simple Material